# Are houris really female? If yes, how can we understand that?

Tags: sex, houri

It is widely believed that houris are female divine creatures who will be married with men in the Heaven.
 Where exactly we know that they are female?
 Can there be male houris for women and female houris for men?
 Can "the virgin houri" also means man who never had sex before?
 Also how do we know that they are not human?

Answers based on Quran first, then Hadith will be appreciated.

Comment: As what i know, male are getting females and a women is getting her husband, If the husband is not in heaven she can choose to be with whoever she like to be If there is no one to her eye she can get a heavenly made man for her. Don't forget that when we enter heaven we won't be thinking about anything that we shouldn't be thinking about. We will be cleansed. Male with a male is forbidden (female with female too) so no that won't be happening. Allah knows best.

Comment: [Which ancient scholars have held the position that the hoors mentioned in the Quran are of both the sexes, and not just female?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18411/which-ancient-scholars-have-held-the-position-that-the-hoors-mentioned-in-the-qu)

Comment: @typod, Sorry I wrote it wrong. I corrected now. I didn't mean homosexuality. I just wanted to know about women's situation.

Comment: @kalahari,  ah okay, don't worry. The case however still stands. There are female and male houris, A female will be an massive beauty, they will be superior compared to a female houri. I read somewhere that they are angels but I'm not sure where i read it. When i have time i will edit this and add another comment. Male and female are equal. A garden is not just for a male also for female

Comment: I am waiting for answers with references, now :)

Answer (score 1):

The Quran uses feminine adjective for them:

> حُورٌ **مَّقْصُورَاتٌ** فِي الْخِيَامِ [55:72](http://tanzil.net/#55:72)

For those who will be married to them The Quran uses masculine pronouns:

> مُتَّكِئِينَ عَلَىٰ سُرُرٍ مَّصْفُوفَةٍ ۖ وَزَوَّجْنَا**هُم** بِحُورٍ عِينٍ [52:20](http://tanzil.net/#52:20)

and

> كَذَٰلِكَ وَزَوَّجْنَا**هُم** بِحُورٍ عِينٍ [44:54](http://tanzil.net/#44:54)

**حور عين** literally means 'fully blackened eyes' like those of gazelle (no sclera). It is used metaphorically for women. (from Lisaan al Arab dictionary)

Therefore, it seems that they are female and human.

Similarly, the place where it is mentioned that they are 'untouched' feminine pronouns/adjectives are used:

> فِيهِنَّ **قَاصِرَاتُ** الطَّرْفِ لَمْ **يَطْمِثْهُنَّ** إِنسٌ
>   قَبْلَهُمْ وَلَا جَانٌّ [55:56](http://tanzil.net/#55:56)

The following verse states a general rule that there will be **pure spouses** for **those who believe and do good works**. Women are there definitely included in them i.e. there will be pure men for them:

> Give the good news to **those who believe and do good works**, that they
>   will have Gardens through which rivers flow: whenever they are given
>   fruit to eat they will say, "This is what we were provided with
>   before," because they were given similar things. And there will be
>   **pure spouses** for them, and they will abide there forever. [2:25](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/2:25)

(Please note that masculine pronouns etc. are used here too which is fine as the Quran is talking about a collection of men and women)

This, however, may refer to simple husband-wife relationship. Therefore, as far as the question of 'male houri for women' is concerned the Qur'an does not make any categorical statement.

Comment: As far as I know, masculine is different from male in Arabic. Masculine more seems like no-gender. Is it right?

Comment: Quran use male adjective for God, doesn't mean Allah is a male.

Comment: @AmericanMuslim Of course it doesn't. My answer is not based on adjective usage for a single entity in isolation.