# Are all ‘houris’ female?

Tags: houri

I found this [article](http://www.dawn.com/news/635343/are-all-houris-female) after looking up the meaning of the word [houri](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houri) that I find untranslated in my copy of the Quran.

It seems to be a well argued point with plenty of references to the Quran,  but it has not appear to have been compiled by a scholar or sheikh.

Is this article correct in saying that not  all houris are female?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.   Houris doesnt imply a gender but rather it is a description.

Comment: @azim I don't  see those on mobile

Comment: @sayyid is this confirmed by anyone scholarly? Maybe in tafsir?

Comment: @Pureferret you could get a better understanding by reading these ahadith from here http://www.sunnah.com/search/?q=houris

Comment: [here is the link](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23996/do-houris-really-female-if-yes-how-can-we-understand-that?rq=1) to the dupilcate question.

Comment: Well it's confirmed by the Arabic language and the scholars of language, like al-Zabidi.  Lane's Lexicon is based on classical Arabic dictionaries.  It's a pretty accurate in English and probably the best found today.